# Using .set_params() function for LinearRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, hyperparameters

I recently started working on Machine Learning with Linear Regression. I have used a `LinearRegression` (`lr`) to predict some values. Indeed, my predictions were bad, and I was asked to change the hyperparameters to obtain better results.

I used the following command to obtain the hyperparameters:

```
lr.get_params().keys() 
lr.get_params()
```

and obtained the following:

```
 'copy_X': True,
 'fit_intercept': True,
 'n_jobs': None,
 'normalize': False,
 'positive': False}
```

and

```
dict_keys(['copy_X', 'fit_intercept', 'n_jobs', 'normalize', 'positive'])
```

Now, this is where issues started to raise. I have tried to find the correct syntax to use the `.set_params()` function, but every answer seemed outside my comprehension.

I have tried to assign a positional arguments since commands such as `lr.set_params('normalize'==True)` returned

```
TypeError: set_params() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

and `lr.set_params(some_params = {'normalize'})` returned

```
ValueError (`ValueError: Invalid parameter some_params for estimator LinearRegression(). Check the list of available parameters with estimator.get_params().keys().
```

Can someone provide a simple explanation of how this function works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `set_params(**params)` where `params` is a dictionary containing the estimator's parameters, see the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html?highlight=set_params#sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.set_params).

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.get_params()
# {'copy_X': True,
#  'fit_intercept': True,
#  'n_jobs': None,
#  'normalize': False,
#  'positive': False}

reg.set_params(**{
    'copy_X': False,
    'fit_intercept': False,
    'n_jobs': -1,
    'normalize': True,
    'positive': True
})

reg.get_params()
# {'copy_X': False,
#  'fit_intercept': False,
#  'n_jobs': -1,
#  'normalize': True,
#  'positive': True}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking the `**` notation, @FlaviaGiammarino's answer is equivalent to:

```py
reg.set_params(
    copy_X=False,
    fit_intercept=False,
    n_jobs=-1,
    normalize=True,
    positive=True
)
```